# How to minimize parameter in row pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have dataframe with bus stop arrival forecast:

```
path_id | forecast | forecast_made_at | bus_id
 int    | datetime |  datetime        | int
```

We make predictions every 5 minutes, so database entries can be duplicated. for example

```
In 11:50 we predict bus #11544 will arrive at 11:59
In 11:50 we predict bus #95447 will arrive at 11:55
--......--
In 11:55 we predict bus #11544 will arrive at 12:02
```

I want to get newest prediction with biggest forecast_made_at parameter:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for k, row in t_data.iterrows():
  prediction = dict(**row)
  forecasts = t_data[t_data["bus_id"] == prediction["bus_id"]] # Forecasts with the same bus_id
  prediction["best"] = (prediction["forecast_made_at"] == max(forecasts["forecast_made_at"]))
  res = res.append(prediction, ignore_index=True)

res = res[res["best"] == True]
```

In this code, we are working with dictionaries and not with pandas objects, so this one is very slow. How can I do this using pandas tools

Comment: can you provide some rows of your dataframe please?

Comment: (55, 12:07, 12:00, 1231), (55, 12:11, 12:00, 1789), (55, 12:08, 12:05:, 1231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a combination of grouping by `bus_id`, sorting by date and selection of most recent row.

One option – dropping duplicates by `bus_id` and only keeping most recent record:

```
t_data.sort_values('forecast_made_at').drop_duplicates(subset=['bus_id'], keep='last')
```

Another option: Grouping by `bus_id` and selecting last record:

```
t_data.sort_values('forecast_made_at').groupby('bus_id').last().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this dataframe as an example

```
   path_id            forecast    forecast_made_at  bus_id
0        1 2018-01-01 14:10:00 2018-01-01 11:10:00       7
1        1 2018-01-01 14:10:00 2018-01-01 10:15:00       7
2        1 2018-01-01 14:10:00 2018-01-01 10:49:00       7
3        2 2018-09-10 03:05:00 2018-09-09 23:05:00       6
4        2 2018-09-10 03:05:00 2018-09-10 03:00:00       6
5        2 2018-09-10 03:05:00 2018-09-10 01:30:00       6
6        3 2018-04-21 17:32:00 2018-04-21 17:31:00       4
7        3 2018-04-21 17:32:00 2018-04-21 17:12:00       4
8        3 2018-04-21 17:32:00 2018-04-21 17:02:00       4
```

You can achieve that with the following

```
new_df = df.loc[df.groupby('forecast')['forecast_made_at'].idxmax()]
print(new_df)

   path_id            forecast    forecast_made_at  bus_id
0        1 2018-01-01 14:10:00 2018-01-01 11:10:00       7
6        3 2018-04-21 17:32:00 2018-04-21 17:31:00       4
4        2 2018-09-10 03:05:00 2018-09-10 03:00:00       6
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates an index containing the "bus_id" and the max "forecast_made_at" for that "bus_id"

```
ids = df.groupby("bus_id", as_index=False).forecast_made_at.max().set_index(["bus_id", "forecast_made_at"]).index
```

Then, we can extract data matching this index from the original datframe as:

```
df.set_index(["bus_id", "forecast_made_at"]).loc[ids].reset_index()
```

I hope this is useful.